# Почему бот Telegram на Python закрывается?

Tags: python, telebot

При запуске бота через консоль, он закрывается автоматически. Поставил `input()` — перестал закрываться, но в Telegram при старте ничего не выводится.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from string import Template

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

user_dict = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city

        keys = ['fullname', 'phone', 'passportNumber', 'address', 'dateOfBirth', 'cartNumber']

        for key in keys:
            self.key = None

#if '/help' or '/start'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message_handler):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('/about')
    itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('reg')
    markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello"
    + message.from_user.first_name
    + ", I'm bot , how can i help you ? ")

#/about
@bot.message_handler(commands=['about'])
def send_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "We successful company .")

# /reg
@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg'])
def user_reg(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('SNG')
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('EC')
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('USA')
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('AS')

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat, 'You region ?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, procces_fullname_step)

def procces_city_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        user_dict[chat_id] = User(message.text)

        #delit old markup
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Full name ?', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, procces_fullname_step)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'opssss...')

input()
```

Comment: потому что сам код надо запустить в работу, а не просто функции описать? почитайте про polling и как он запускается.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Я этого не вижу в коде, но так бот запускает цикл прослушивания и не закрывается.